# Как запустить исходники com.android.browser?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, библиотеки

Скачал с `github.com` исходники стандартного андроидовского браузера:

[`platform_packages_apps_browser`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser)

Открыл проект в Eclipse. Тот показал кучу ошибок, в основном, связанных с не подключенными библиотеками, но есть и ошибки связанные с тем, что класс подключен, а соответственного метода, который вызывается, в классе нет. Кстати, следует отметить, что при открытии проекта через `File -> New -> Android Project ->` далее поставить вкладку `Create project from existing sourse` и выбрать в графе `Location` путь к папке с исходниками `com.android.browser`, то не выбирается версия Android, под которую написана программа в графе `Build Target` и приходится её задавать самому, я перепробовал выбрать по очереди все и всё равно возникают одни и те же ошибки.
Вот неполный список не найденных классов:

`import android.net.WebAddress;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
import android.text.IClipboard;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
import android.text.IClipboard;
import android.speech.RecognizerResultsIntent;`

и т.д.

Так же не были найдены методы или переменные в подключенных классах:

`Browser.getVisitedLike(cr, url)
Browser.BookmarkColumns.THUMBNAIL
Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_THUMBNAIL_INDEX`

и т.д.

Пробовал искать `com.android.browser` на других сайтах, все что находил показывало аналогичную картину. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, в чем кроется проблема, если в вроде как все стандартные библиотеки и классы есть, а проект не создается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно `android hidden API` и `class-full-debug.jar`, эта библиотека подключается как user library и в order ставится выше всего.

Comment: То есть надо использовать скрытое API андроида? Это получается, что браузер привязан к конкретному девайсу. И можете подсказать, как можно достать эту библиотеку classes-full-debug.jar ?

Comment: Hidden API это не значит, что этот код привязан к конкретному девайсу, это значит что код браузера привязан к какой-то версии API, которое в будущем возможно будет меняться. Class full debug .jar можно получить полностью постороив у себя платформу, как это делается, написано на sources.android.com. Есть альтернативные способы, например: http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/